# How to upgrade the PHP CLI version but not the CGI version?

Tags: php, whm

I have a WHM which hosts multiple hosts that uses different PHP CGI versions, so I can't simply upgrade to a common PHP version for all hosts. But I want to upgrade CLI version.

Currently I have multiple PHP version and am using php handler (suPHP) to handle the differences between hosts.

Can I only upgrade the CLI version?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Might be a better question for [Server Fault](//serverfault.com)

Comment: @Jim Wright Ubuntu 14